# What's an example of using an overridden property in the Base Class initialization (either directly or indirectly)?

Tags: kotlin

> It means that, by the time of the base class constructor execution, the properties declared or overridden in the derived class are not yet initialized. If any of those properties are used in the base class initialization logic (either directly or indirectly, through another overridden open member implementation), it may lead to incorrect behavior or a runtime failure. When designing a base class, you should therefore avoid using open members in the constructors, property initializers, and init blocks.

I was studying Inheritence from Kotlin docs, and I got stuck here. There was another post which asked a question about this, but the answers were just what the docs said in a different way.

- To be clear, I understood the data flow between constructors and inheritence. What I couldn't understand was how we can use an overridden property in a base class initialization. It says

> It could happen directly or indirectly

What does this actually mean? How can the base class can somehow access to the overridden property in the derived class?

- Also, it said

> You should therefore avoid using open members in the constructors,
> property initializers and init blocks.

So how can we properly use open properties?

**EDIT FOR THE COMMENT:**

```
fun main ()
{
    val d = Derived("Test2")
}

open class Base()
{
    open val something:String = "Test1"

    init
    {
        println(something)  //prints null
    }
}

class Derived(override val something: String): Base()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What does this actually mean? How can the base class can somehow access to the overridden property in the derived class?

This is one direct way:

```kotlin
abstract class Base {
    abstract val something: String

    init {
        println(something)
    }
}

class Child(override val something: String): Base()

fun main() {
    Child("Test") // prints null! because the property is not initialized yet
}
```

This prints `null`, which is pretty bad for a non-nullable `String` property.

> > You should therefore avoid using open members in the constructors, property initializers and init blocks.
>
> So how can we properly use open properties?

You can use these properties in regular methods on the base class (or in custom property getters):

```kotlin
abstract class Base {
    
    abstract val something: String

    fun printSomething() {
        println(something)
    }
}

class Child(override val something: String): Base()

fun main() {
    Child("Test").printSomething() // correctly prints "Test"
}
```

---

EDIT: Here are some clarifications regarding the follow-up questions in the comments.

> I couldn't quite get why the code in the init block went for the parameter in the child class constructor

I think you might be confused by Kotlin's compact syntax for the primary constructors in general, which probably makes the debugger's flow hard to understand. In the `Child` declaration, we actually declare many things:

- the *argument* `something` passed to the `Child`'s primary constructor
- the *property* `something` on the `Child` class, which overrides the parent's one
- the call to the parent constructor (`Base()`)

When `Child()` is called, it immediately calls the `Base()` no-arg constructor, which runs the `init` block.

> We didn't even delegate the base constructor with a parameter or anything, but it still went for the parameter who did the overriding

You might be mixing *declarations* and *runtime* here. Although we *declare* things in the `Base` class and in the `Child` class, there is only 1 instance at runtime (an instance of `Child`) in this example code.

So, in fact, there is only 1 property called `something` here (only one place in memory). If the `init` block accesses this property, it can only be the property of the child instance. We don't need to pass anything to the `Base` constructor because the `init` block is effectively executed with the data/fields of the `Child` instance.

Maybe you would be less confused if you saw the Java equivalent of this. It's obvious if you think of the abstract `something` as a declaration of a getter `getSomething()`. The child class overrides this `getSomething()` method and declares a private `something` field, the getter returns the current value of the field `something`. But that field is only initialized *after* the constructor of the parent (and the init block) finished executing.

Comment: I tried to follow the data follow by debugging the first example. It shows that after you get to the init block, it jumps back to the constructor(or maybe the class) to get the value of 'something' and because it's not initialized it gives null. Firstly, I want to ask if I understood the flow correctly, if so, I couldn't quite get why the code in the init block went for the parameter in the child class constructor. We didn't even delegate the base constructor with a parameter or anything, but it still went for the parameter who did the overriding.

Comment: @JockyCracker maybe you're confused by Kotlin's compact syntax for the primary constructors in general. I edited my answer.

Comment: It was rather me mixing up the terms parameter and property, mb. I meant how the superclass was able to use the property of the subclass in the init block. I also tried a non-abstract example, and my current understanding is that: We can write to print 'something' in superclass without any compile-time error because the superclass, within itself, actually has that property, but when we use 'override' in a subclass, and create an instance of it, it overrides the value for the property in the superclass. Is it right? I'll also add the one I created to test.

Comment: @JockyCracker right, only the overridden definition of the property is available to the `Child` instance, and there is only a `Child` instance. The `init` block is effectively running as part of the initialization of that `Child` instance, even though the code for it is defined somewhere else. You can think of it as if the `init` block was itself in the child instance, and declared first (which is why it doesn't see the initial value of `something`).